# Save QColor and QFont in a QDomElement?

Tags: c++, qt

How do you save things like `QColor` and `QFont` in a `QDomElement` ?

Comment: Please **do not** edit the content of your question away. Leave it be, so that other people with the same problem can find it and the answers. If you do, it also means that the people who take the time to leave an answer have wasted their time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should do serialization `QColor` and `QFont` to `XML`. This helps you [Serializing Qt Data Types](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/datastreamformat.html) and [Data Streams](http://books.google.ru/books?id=nyxoEiGHKtoC&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&dq=serialization%20QColor%20to%20xml%20qt&source=bl&ots=oJnuoxJdzK&sig=45yY3fBFHbvSZD_glg94_3y0zj8&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=ff-pUNHFG-rV4QSPt4HYDg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=serialization%20QColor%20to%20xml%20qt&f=false)